# Asignar colores a una matriz de confusión en Python

Tags: python, print, matriz, seaborn

Tengo una matriz de confusión 18x18. Para una mejor visualización de errores, quiero hacer un mapa de colores en función del valor que tenemos en nuestra matriz normalizada.

Quiero hacer una gradación de colores en la que visualizar de manera más adecuada los datos. Por ejemplo, las zonas en las que los aciertos sean mayores al 80%, tendrían una escala de colores  diferente a las zonas en las que los aciertos estén comprendidos entre el 20% y el 80%. Por último, las zonas donde los aciertos sean menores al 20%, tendrían una gradación de color distintas.

Tengo el siguiente código (donde realizamos un dataframe y con ella nuestra matriz de confusión).

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
    
working_path = os.getcwd() #sirve para establecer en qué carpeta estamos trabajando (ruta), ahora todos los archivos q se encuentren en esa carpeta solo los tenemos que llamar con su nombre
    
df = pd.read_csv("salida.txt",delimiter="\t") #Hacemos un dataframe, importando el archivo txt separado por tabuladores
    
df.rename(columns={'Number of Syllables': 'NSyllables'}, inplace = True) #Cambiamos (acortamos) nombres de la columna que indica el nº de sílabas

conf_matC = pd.crosstab(df['TargetC'], df['RespC'], rownames=['Target'], colnames=['Response'], margins = True); #Matriz de confusión para CONSONANTES
ncmC = conf_matC.drop(["All", "**"], axis = 0); #Quitamos la fila All (no da información relevante) Consonantes
confusion_matrixC = ncmC.drop(["All", "**","gr", "zr"], axis = 1); #Matriz de confusión total Consonantes - Quitamos la columna All (no nos da información) Consonantes
ncmC1 = confusion_matrixC/confusion_matrixC.max().astype(np.float64); #Normalizamos matriz confusión Consonantes
normarlize_confusion_matrixC = ncmC1.round(2); #Redondeamos los datos a dos decimales en df Consonantes

printed_matrixC = sn.heatmap(normarlize_confusion_matrixC, cmap='Oranges', annot=False); #Imprimimos matriz de confusion con mapa de calor, Consonantes
```

Con este código, obtenemos la siguiente matriz:

```
Response     b   ch     d    f     g     k  ...    rr     s     t    x    y     z
Target                                      ...                                  
b         1.00  0.0  0.10  0.0  0.08  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
ch        0.00  1.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
d         0.00  0.0  1.00  0.0  0.08  0.00  ...  0.08  0.00  0.02  0.0  0.0  0.00
f         0.00  0.0  0.00  1.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.36
g         0.03  0.0  0.00  0.0  1.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
k         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  1.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
l         0.00  0.0  0.03  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
m         0.03  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.08  0.00  ...  0.08  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
n         0.00  0.0  0.10  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.08  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
ny        0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
p         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.04  0.0  0.0  0.00
r         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.08  0.00  0.02  0.0  0.0  0.00
rr        0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  1.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
s         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  1.00  0.00  0.0  0.0  0.00
t         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.09  ...  0.00  0.00  1.00  0.0  0.0  0.12
x         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  1.0  0.0  0.04
y         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.0  1.0  0.00
z         0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  ...  0.00  0.12  0.00  0.0  0.0  1.00
```

Visto como imágen en el dataframe:

[image: Dataframe matriz 18x18]

En un principio he hecho un heatmap de mi matriz de confusión, pero me da varios fallos de visualización tal y como se aprecia en la imagen siguiente.

[image: Heatmap matriz 18x18]

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema e imprimir la matriz por colores sin que se me corten los números? ¿Podría hacer diferentes gradaciones de colores según el grado de acierto tal y como se explica anteriormente?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de la indentación en el código? Recuerda que en python es relevante. Puedes pegar todo el código y ponerlo en un bloque de formato de código usando ``` encima y debajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tamaño de las anotaciones se puede configurar a través de `annot_kws={size=6}`. Para cambiar el tamaño de toda la figura, habría que crear la figura y el `ax` explícitamente, y dar el `ax` como parámetro a `sns.heatmap`.

Para ver más gradaciones del color naranja, una transformación logarítmica puede ayudar (matplotlib lo llama `LogNorm`).

Para tener el diagonal en otro color, el uso de una máscara permite primero dibujar los valores más pequeños y después otro heatmap con los grandes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

cons = ['b', 'c', 'ch', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ',
        'p', 'q', 'r', 'rr', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
N = len(cons)

ncmC1 = np.abs(np.identity(N) - np.random.uniform(0, 0.2, (N, N)) ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.heatmap(ncmC1, mask=ncmC1 > 0.5,
            cmap='Oranges', norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=0.001, vmax=10), vmin=0.001, vmax=0.5,
            annot=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={"size": 6},
            xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(ncmC1, mask=ncmC1 <= 0.5,
            cmap='Blues', norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1), vmin=0.5, vmax=1, cbar=False,
            annot=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={"size": 6},
            xticklabels=cons, yticklabels=cons, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo del plot]